# How to perform an Auto Increment for specific pattern in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

In my project,the ID column is auto incremented by 1, and i need to make a custom pattern for it.

Instead of :

1

2

3

...

I need it like this `Ad-1-(mm)-(yy)`

mm:the current month (consists of two  digits), 
yy:the current year (consists of two  digits),

for example, if i want to create records this month ,the ID should appear like this :

`Ad-1-10-19`  (1st record)

`Ad-2-10-19`  (2nd record)

`Ad-3-10-19`  (3rd record)
.......

Could you please advise on the right approach to do it ?

Comment: You would still need a normal ID column and then use a method to create the computed ID column values from the database generated ID.

Comment: should i place that method in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're still going to keep the integer primary key ID column. You could add a void function that sets that property and call it inside the controller;

```
// your model
public class Product{

   [Key]
   public int productId {get;set;}

   public string code {get;set;}

   private void setCode() {
      this.code= "Ad-" + this.productId.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-yy");
   }
}

// your controller
public class ProductController : Controller(){
   public ActionResult CreateProduct(){
      Product p = new Product();
      product.setCode();
   }
}
```

Or you could put it in the class' constructor, so that everytime you instantiate an object, it is automatically created;

```
// your model
public class Product{

   // constructor
   public Product(){
      this.setCode();
   }

   [Key]
   public int productId {get;set;}

   public string code {get;set;}

   private void setCode() {
      this.code= "Ad-" + this.productId.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-yy");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , the idea is great and it works ! , but the ID and Month are not represented properly,for example, when the ID is 6 , the code is represented    Ad044-19

Comment: @MOHAMMADALMASALMA Sorry, `DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");` returns the current minute twice. It should be `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-yy");` I updated the code.

Comment: Oh, it seems that the Product id is 0, place the code strategically in your controller; maybe after the object is created / inserted to the DB.

Comment: the issue of the month has been solved , but for the ID still 0 , i didn't understand what you mean by placing the code strategically... i called the methode in the controller as you've mentioned , but it didn't work.

Comment: Method is to be called after dbContext.SaveChanges() line, so that ID will be inserted automatically by EF and can be used to compute the code value.

Comment: I did it that way , but still gives 0 for ID

Comment: Controller code: `using (DBContextModel db = new DBContextModel()) { Product newProd = new Product(); db.Products.Add(newProd); db.SaveChanges(); newProd.setCode(); db.SaveChanges(); //note second call to save changes return View(); }`